# How to run a batch file from an SSRS 2008 R2 report by using a code?

Tags: asp.net, batch-file, scripting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have an SSRS report on which there are several text boxes. On the click of a particular text box, a batch file should be executed.

Comment: What kind of batch file you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `SSRS` there is now way to detect the `Click` event of any control so you can not execute the script directly. But there is one trick you can use

1) Create webpage which will execute the actual batch for you

2) **Right click Textbox** and select Textbox Properties-> Action-> Goto URL

3) In the textbox that appears give URL of your webpage

4) That way the webpage will execute the batch file for you.

---

There is other way that is you could register your own URL protocol with the systems so you could put a `URL` in the report like   `ssrs://yourapplicaton` then when its clicked it will run the associated application have a look [at this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx) it will explain it better than i m doing.

So 1) Register your own URL protocol

2) Follow 2 and 3 from above

3) And set your registered URL

Comment: Thank you so much! I am quite new to this field. Can you help me with  the web page as well?

Comment: It would be simple webpage. Here is the blog to get you going http://asp.net-tutorials.com/basics/first-website/ . And if this answer helped you please accept it as answer so question can be closed. Start with website if any issues ask new questions on SO.